# Kubernetes, Cannot access exposed services

Tags: kubernetes

**Kubernetes version:**
v1.10.3

**Docker version:**
17.03.2-ce

**Operating system and kernel:**
Centos 7

**Steps to Reproduce:**
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/service-access-application-cluster/

**Results:**

[root@rd07 rd]# kubectl describe services example-service

Name:                     example-service
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   run=load-balancer-example
Annotations:              
Selector:                 run=load-balancer-example
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.108.214.162
Port:                       9090/TCP
TargetPort:               9090/TCP
NodePort:                   31105/TCP
Endpoints:                192.168.1.23:9090,192.168.1.24:9090
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:

**Expected:**

Expect to be able to curl the cluster ip defined in the kubernetes service

I'm not exactly sure which is the so called "public-node-ip", so I tried every related ip address, only when using the master ip as the "public-node-ip" it shows "No route to host".

I used "netstat" to check if the endpoint is listened.

I tried "https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/6139" to flush my iptables, and it was not working at all.

I tried "https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/",  "nslookup hostnames.default" is not working.

The services seems working perfectly fine, but the services still cannot be accessed.

I'm using "calico" and the "flannel" was also tried.

I tried so many tutorials of apply services, they all cannot be accessed.

I'm new to kubernetes, plz if anyone could help me.

Comment: Are you trying to curl the load-balancer IP to connect to your nodes?

Comment: Yes, stucked at the step "curl http://<public-node-ip>:<node-port>"

Comment: Your loadbalancer is exposed in 9090 and your loadbalancer ip is 10.108.214.162. You should be curling the 10.108.214.162:9090

Comment: It says No route to host. [root@rd07 rd]# curl 10.108.214.162:9090
curl: (7) Failed connect to 10.108.214.162:9090; No route to host.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on any public cloud you are not supposed to get public ip address at `ip a` command. But even though the port will be exposed to `0.0.0.0:31105`

Here is the sample file you can verify for your configuration:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: app-name
  name: bss
  namespace: default
spec:
  externalIPs:
  - 172.16.2.2
  - 172.16.2.3
  - 172.16.2.4
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - port: 9090
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9090
  selector:
    k8s-app: bss
  sessionAffinity: ClientIP
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Just replace your `<private-ip>` at `externalIPs:` and do curl your public ip with your node port.

If you are using any cloud to deploy application, Also verify configuration from cloud security groups/firewall for opening port.

Hope this may help.

Thank you!

Comment: thx a lot for answering. I'm wondering if the kubernetes can't work without iptables. cuz I stopped the firewalld service.

Answer (score 0):

My k8s cluster is 1 master and 1 node.
The service pod is running on the node.
So I used http://nodeip:31105, it shows "Hello Kubernetes!".
But http://masterip:31105 still not working, is it suppose to be right?
I checked the endpoint listen, 31105 is listened on master.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command:

```
kubectl get service
```

If your service "TYPE" is "NodePort" and "EXTERNAL-IP" column is "none" then you can access or curl your service from the URL: `http://<localmachine_ip>:<port_no>`

Port number also available in the result of the command `kubectl get service` in the column `PORT(S)`.
For example, if the value of `PORT(S)` is `1000:31918/TCP`, then the port number is `31918`.

If the service type is `ClusterIP` then you first delete the service using the command `kubectl delete service <servie_name>` and use the following command:

```
kubectl expose deployment <deployment_name> --type=NodePort --port=80
```

This command will start the service of `TYPE` = `NodePort`

Note: you have to expose the deployment. I assume that you are aware of deployment in K8s.